# Translating Matlab (Octave) group coloring code into python (numpy, pyplot)

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, octave, hsv

I want to translate the following group coloring **octave** function to **python** and use it with **pyplot**.

Function input: 
**x** - Data matrix (m x n) 
**a** - A parameter. 
**index** - A vector of size "m" with values in range [: a] 
(For example if a = 4, index can be [random.choice(range(4)) for i in range(m)]

The values in "index" indicate the number of the group the "m"th data point belongs to.
The function should plot all the data points from x and color them in different colors (Number of different colors is "a").

The function in octave:

```
p = hsv(a); % This is a x 3 metrix
colors = p(index, :); % ****This is m x 3 metrix****
scatter(X(:,1), X(:,2), 10, colors);
```

---

I couldn't find a function like hsv in python, so I wrote it myself (I think I did..):

```
 p = colors.hsv_to_rgb(numpy.column_stack((
numpy.linspace(0, 1, a), numpy.ones((a ,2)) )) )
```

But I can't figure out how to do the matrix selection p(index, :) in python (numpy). 
Specially because the size of "index" is bigger then "a".

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you want to take an `m x 3` of `HSV` values, and convert each row to `RGB`?

```
import numpy as np
import colorsys
mymatrix = np.matrix([[11,12,13],
                      [21,22,23],
                      [31,32,33]])

def to_hsv(x):
    return colorsys.rgb_to_hsv(*x)

#Apply the to_hsv function to each matrix row.
print np.apply_along_axis(to_hsv, axis=1, arr=mymatrix)
```

This produces:

```
[[  0.5   0.   13. ]
 [  0.5   0.   23. ]
 [  0.5   0.   33. ]]
```

Follow through on your comment:

If I understand you have a matrix `p` that is an `a x 3` matrix, and you want to randomly select rows from the matrix over and over again, until you have a new matrix that is `m x 3`?

Ok. Let's say you have a matrix `p` defined as follows:

```
a = 5
p = np.random.randint(5, size=(a, 3))
```

Now, make a list of random integers between the range `0 -> 3` (index starts at `0` and ends to `a-1`), That is `m` in length:

```
m = 20
index = np.random.randint(a, size=m)
```

Now access the right indexes and plug them into a new matrix:

```
p_prime = np.matrix([p[i] for i in index])
```

Produces a `20 x 3` matrix.

Comment: Hi, annon, Thanks for the quick answer. Unfortunately, your answer is not exactly what I was looking for, I think I wasn't clear enough about what I need. I'll try to explain better: My main problem (AS I understand it) is not converting from HSV to RGB, I think I solved it using the colors.hsv_to_rgb function above. My main problem is how to do the octave selection p(index, :) in numpy

Comment: I'll try to give an example to be more clear: if a = 4 and m = 20 then the p metrix is 4 x 3 but the index vector is 20 x 1, now I need to select 20 rows from p based on the values (1 - 4) of the 20 elements in index.